# associate IP with hostname without editing /etc/hosts

Tags: dns, hostname, tcpdump, hosts

I know I can associate hostname with my IP address in `/etc/hosts`:

```
1.2.3.4   foo
```

and then, for example in `tcpdump` output, I will see `foo` instead of my IP address (if `-n` was not used)

Anyways, can I temporarily add such `IP -> hostname` mapping on the commandline, without actually editing the file?

Lets suppose I connect to a wifi, and get some random IP. I want this IP to be resolved into my hostname in tcpdump **for this current session** (without adding an entry permanently into `/etc/hosts`.

## UPDATE:

In case it was not clear from my question, and the title, I am  looking for a solution how to do this without modifying `/etc/hosts`.

In a same way as I can use the command `hostname` to set the hostname for current session (ie until next restart) without having to edit `/etc/hostname`, I am looking for setting up reverse lookup for current session (ie until next restart) without having to modify `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: You could use `sed 's/IP/name/g'`.

Comment: One way would be to set up hooks in whatever script you use to connect to wifi to modify `/etc/hosts` on connect/disconnect.

Comment: @Shadur - I thought I made it clear in my question, and in the title: "without modifying /etc/hosts".

Comment: I don't understand why you can't simply use `sed`. It's straightforward, fast, simple and doesn't touch host system files.

Comment: Your alternatives would be to host a very tiny forwarding DNS server and have your link-up/link-down hooks update *it*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hostname resolution service of the C library (which is used by almost all software that needs hostname resolution) is controlled primarily by the `hosts:` line in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file. Each keyword on that line causes the corresponding `libnss_*.so` library to be loaded, and those libraries will ultimately handle the hostname resolution requests from the applications.

If your distribution includes a package called `nss-myhostname` (or any other package that will provide a `libnss_myhostname.so.*` library), then you could install that package, add `myhostname` to the `hosts:` line of `nsswitch.conf`, and then that library will automatically associate the locally configured system hostname with any and all IP addresses configured to network interfaces on your system. With this configuration, you would not need to run any commands to update the association: it will all happen automatically. It will also associate your local hostname with IP address 127.0.0.2 (and IPv6 address ::1) if you have no IP addresses configured on your system at all.

If the `hosts:` line of your `nsswitch.conf` includes the keyword `resolve` or your `/etc/resolv.conf` has a line `nameserver 127.0.0.53`, then you are using `systemd-resolved` as your DNS resolver. It can provide similar automatic association for your local hostname to any locally configured IP addresses as `libnss_myhostname` (see above). If this is your case, see `man systemd-resolved` and read the chapter titled `SYNTHETIC RECORDS`. It will also include optional mDNS (see below) and LLMNR (link-local multicast name resolver/responder) functionality, which might also provide local hostname resolution in a roundabout way.

If the `hosts:` line of your `nsswitch.conf` includes a hostname resolution service that can use multicast-DNS (mDNS) like `mdns4_minimal` *and* your system includes a mDNS responder (e.g. `avahi-daemon`), it might enable automatic resolving of `<hostname>.local` to the local system's IP addresses, and vice versa.

If the `hosts:` line of your `nsswitch.conf` includes any other options (or your distribution offers other `libnss_*.so` libraries), you will have to investigate the functionalities offered by them on your own, since you did not specify your distribution.

If the `hosts:` line of your `nsswitch.conf` includes only the classic `files` and `dns` keywords, *or* you need to assign names to IP addresses that are not currently configured to any of the local network interfaces (e.g. names for IP addresses of other hosts), then see the methods in [Marcus Müller's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714957/258991).

If none of these answers are suitable to you, then I'm afraid the answer will be "No, there is no functionality like you're asking for. But if you have programming skills, there would be nothing stopping you from implementing it yourself" - and the list of possible methods above and in Marcus Müller's answer should give you ideas on the interfaces you could use to plug your own solution into.

Comment: `libnss-myhostname` is exactly what IO was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

So, what tcpdump is doing here is triggering a reverse lookup; that you say it usually seems to be able to respect /etc/hosts entries in that suggests it uses libc's `getnameinfo` function for that. Like one would expect.

So, that means you need to modify the behaviour of a rather central piece of your runtime environment; /etc/hosts does indeed not seem to me to be the most intrusive way of doing that!

Now, taking your "for this session only" seriously: You need to define what session means:

- If "session" means your current run of `tcpdump` (or all processes started from one shell), you could use `LD_PRELOAD` to load your own little library that just replaces the `getnameinfo` function with your own version, that just actually passes through all arguments to the original function, but only after checking the address requested against the address whose name you want to fake; whether you read that address from a file, an environment variable or from the active connections, up to you
- If "session" means "active network connection", just tell networkmanager to not use the resolver that the network autoconfiguration (DHCP) suggests to use, but use your own resolver running locally, and use systemd unit files triggered post-bringup and -bringdown to add/remove entries in that resolver. This will affect all users.
- If "session" means something where you want to run many programs: Using a script, copy your original /etc/hosts to a new file, adding the desirable line. Then, make a mount namespace where you use that modified file. Something like

```bash
#!/bin/bash
modified_hosts=$(mktemp XXXXXXX.etchosts)
cp /etc/hosts "${modified_hosts}"
echo "$1 ownhost" >> "${modified_hosts}"

method="unshare"
#method="container"

if [[ ${method} = "unshare" ]]
then
  unshare --mount --map-root-user \
     bash --rcfile \
        <(echo . ~/.bashrc; \
          mount --bind --make-private "${modified_hosts}" /etc/hosts; \
          echo "You're now in a mount space of your own, /etc/hosts has been modified."\
         )
else
  container_image="fedora:36"
  podman run -it --rm -v "${modified_hosts}:/etc/hosts:Z" "${container_image}"
fi
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution without modifying `/etc/hosts`. I thought I made it clear in my question and in the title. Imagine the root filesystem is mounted read-only.

Comment: yes, I described three solutions where you don't have to modify the system-wide /etc/hosts. The last one uses a modified copy of /etc/hosts (stored somewhere temporary), which only applies to the programs you start in the namespace. Please re-read my answer if your impression was I recommend you edit /etc/hosts! This literally does not happen anywhere in my answer.

Comment: thank you, I understand now. But turns out the solution suggested by telcoM is exactly what I was looking for, so I have accepted that answer.

Comment: I don't honestly get it, if you have an unmodifiable root file system, you can't modify nsswitch.conf, either, but I guess you do you :)

Comment: What's the setting of `method` for?

Comment: Literally in the next line of code.

Comment: Yes, but what's it for? When would you need to change it to `container`?

Comment: I described multiple methods in my answer's text. So I let you choose the method you want to try in the script.